# MKMapView Not Loading When Called on an NSThread?

Tags: iphone, mkmapview, nsthread

I am creating a MKMapView in a method named "generateMap". From inside viewDidLoad, this works:

```
[self generateMap];
```

but this causes the map to quickly load and then disappear, leaving only the blank grey grid:

```
[NSThread detachNewThreadSelector:@selector(generateMap) toTarget:self withObject:nil];
```

Any ideas why this might be happening when I call the method through a thread?

---

I ended up doing this:

```
-(void)viewDidLoad {
[NSThread detachNewThreadSelector:@selector(spinTheSpinner) toTarget:self withObject:nil];
[self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(generateMap) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:NO];
[super viewDidLoad];
}
```

This allows me to have a spinner (UIActivityIndicator) and load the MKMapView as I want. I set "waitUntilDone:No]" so that the screen switches the MapView before it is done with generateMap. Otherwise, we would not see the spinner and would only see a blank screen until generateMap was done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think it is advisable to try to update the UI through anything but the main thread.

What happens when you try to run `-generateMap` on the main thread with `-performSelectorOnMainThread:withObject:waitUntilDone:`?

For example:

```
[self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(generateMap) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:YES];
```

Comment: I set ...waitUntilDone:NO]; so the screen does not sit there blank.

Answer (score 0):

First off, can I see the `generateMap` method?  Second, a more sufficient way to perform a selector is by saying

```
[self performSelector:@selector(generateMap)];
```

Comment: Or, simply, `[self generateMap];`