# Annotations not appearing on MKMapView

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, mkmapview

I have set up an `MKMapView` and have plotted annotations based on data from Google Places. Here's the code I am using: http://pastie.org/5187978.

But these annotations do not show on the map. I have tried to log them and it appears that they have all been added successfully - but they just don't appear on the map.

It's really strange. Why is this happening?

Comment: at a quick look the code seems fine. Is your `-(MKAnnotationView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForAnnotation:(id <MKAnnotation>)annotation` method called?

Comment: Uhm, not sure if it could be a problem, but you are calling [self plotPositions:places]; from an async queue --> not the main thread. Try to call it on main thread. Look at this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2648538/mkmapview-not-loading-when-called-on-an-nsthread

Comment: If you intend to use this in iOS 6 you should be aware that under section 10.1.1.g of the Google Maps API terms of service (https://developers.google.com/maps/terms) you can not display their data on non-Google maps.

Comment: @LombaX yes, that method is being called. I have also changed [self plotPositions:places]; to be called from the main thread now but it still doesn't show any of the annotations. Craig, that sucks :(

Comment: Can you post your updated code? :-)

Comment: Sure: http://pastie.org/5189365

Comment: uhm...it seems really strange. And didAddAnnotationViews is called, right? Try to comment out all the dispatch async and execute all code syncronously on the main thread, just to be sure that it doesn't work even syncronously...no other ideas for the moment :-(

Answer (score 0):

This may not be your issue, but just to help other people - check to make sure the coordinates of your annotations exist on a real map by pasting them into some online map (like maps.bing.com).  If you have your coordinates backwards for example, the annotation will be added and then silently discarded by the system.